# How to get a geometry from a Mapbox GL Native GeoJSONSource?

Tags: nativescript, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using the Mapbox GL Native Android SDK v 7.1.2 in a [NativeScript {N}](https://www.nativescript.org/) app.

I have a line drawn on a map using a GeoJSON source.

I would like to retrieve the geometry from the line at a later point in the code (as opposed to keeping the coordinates lying around separately).

I am able to get a reference to the source of the line using [Style.getSource(id)](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/Style.html#getSource-java.lang.String-) however I can't find an example or explanation how to correctly form an Expression filter for [querySourceFeatures()](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/sources/GeoJsonSource.html#querySourceFeatures-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression-) to get the geometry of the first feature from the list.

Not including a parameter to querySourceFeatures() causes NativeScript not to be able to resolve the call but passing null to it returns an empty list.

How can I form an [Expression filter](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/expressions/Expression.html) to return the geometry of the first feature from a GeoJSON source?

Comment: Did you try [Expression.at](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/expressions/Expression.html#at-java.lang.Number-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression-)?

Comment: What is the second parameter supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in the Android Mapbox GL Native SDK you cannot immediately query a source for it's geometry after you have added it.

To get all features from a source you can use:

```
source.querySourceFeatures( com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.literal(true));
```

however, you have to give the map a chance to update the source before calling this method. In my test I just did a:

```
setTimeout( () => {
  ....
}, 500 );
```

In production you'd probably set a callback [onDidBecomeIdleListener](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapView.OnDidBecomeIdleListener.html).

Sadly, I noticed that the source values are modified after being added to the map. What I query from the source does not exactly match what I put in, so this approach turned out not to be useful for me.

Comment: What about adding a button to invoke querySourceFeatures() after the map is loaded? I've used onDidBecomeIdleListener but it returns the empty result.